# Unable to get notifications in Safari

Tags: safari, notifications

I'm trying to switch from Chrome to Safari on Mac (Ventura). But I'm not getting notifications (Google Voice, Reddit, Gmail) ... and no site "asks" for permission to notify me.

Also nothing appears in **Settings > Websites.**

What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: I would start by disabling ad-blocking or web-filtering software, if you have any. Also any "anti-virus."

Comment: @LincD. I think I would heavily prefer keeping all those and then allow notifications - the answer should not require this loss of security

Comment: I'm suggesting a test. If some third-party software that you want to keep is causing the problem, you'll have to refer to the developer. "Anti-virus" software does not increase security, quite the contrary. All it does is cause problems.

Comment: Strange that your list of "apps asked for permission" is empty. I guess you need to visit a few websites and see what happens, in case something filters out the requests for permission (iSP or anti-virus software),